# Laravel: .htaccess Rewrite the "public" & "laravel" to other folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel, laravel-4

I am currently hosting my website on a Shared hosting and I would like my primary domain folder "public_html" to point to [root]/website1/public_html (actually: [root]/public_html)

Actual working folder structure:

```
[root]/laravel
[root]/public_html
```

It's working fine by typing my domain name.

PS: I have modified laravel config and htaccess to work with "public_html" instead of "public"

Actual .htaccess looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

However, I need to modify my folder structure to this:

```
[root]/website1/laravel
[root]/website1/public_html
```

I asked the hosting's support if they can only change the "live folder" to point to "[root]/website1/public_html" and they cannot, the support told me that I need to do it via a .htaccess file in the actual "[root]/public_html"...

I have tried many things/combination and the only result I get after 2 hours is Internal server Error :(

I am not advanced enough in .htaccess and mod_rewrite config so I would like to know if someone could help me configure that .htaccess that will be in [root]/public_html

Thanks in advance!

Raphaël

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using 4 or 5 ?

Comment: I am using version 4.2, is there a difference with mod-rewrite?